# Is there something like Things for Windows?

Tags: gtd, things-for-mac

[Things](http://culturedcode.com/things/) is really nice [GTD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getting_Things_Done) (Getting Things Done) app only for Mac.

Is there something like Things for Windows?

The closest one I've found is [Doit.im](http://doit.im/). But I've heard that it is unstable and its website seems outdated.

Comment: Are you looking for a web based or desktop application? Or multi-platform?

Comment: If you've searched, what options have you dismissed?

Comment: It should be a desktop app for windows 7. The option I've found are poor in their interface like: http://chandlerproject.org/ and http://www.checkettsweb.com/tw/gtd_tiddlywiki.htm. I really need something similar to Things.

Comment: I found Doit.im but just watch the outdated look of the download page of their site: https://i.doit.im/download

Comment: If there is no one and I must to pick a web based app. I like this one: http://www.producteev.com

Comment: It is helpful, when you are looking for an alternative to Foo to (1) say *what* Foo does (you can imagine a user reading this question who has the perfect solution, but has never heard of get things done...) and (2) provide a link to a more extensive resource. It would also help to say *what* features and interface elements you like. The better the question you right, the better your chances of getting good answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Nirvana](https://www.nirvanahq.com/). It's web-based, rather than desktop-based like Things, but is very similar in UI, and, since it's online, can be accessed from anywhere. As someone who simultaneously uses PCs and Macs, I long since ditched Things for Nirvana.

Comment: It has an ok iPhone app too.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [GeeTeeDee](http://codea.ru/gtd/).  It's simple but well-polished.

Comment: I really like the screenshots of that, I might give it a try. I'd +1, but I'm out of votes. I'll try to remember though

Answer (score 0):

Try using evernote ...synchs with everything and is searchable...

http://lifehacker.com/5952540/get-things-done-with-evernote-using-templates